# How to write a Mongo query that returns records having a specific key?

Tags: mongodb

I have populated some record in my MongoDB as under

```
db.products.insert({ "_id" : { "oid" : "507d95d5719dbef170f15bfe" }, "name" : "Phone Service Basic Plan", "type" : "service", "monthly_price" : 40, "limits" : { "voice" : { "units" : "minutes", "n" : 400, "over_rate" : 0.05 }, "data" : { "units" : "gigabytes", "n" : 20, "over_rate" : 1 }, "sms" : { "units" : "texts sent", "n" : 100, "over_rate" : 0.001 } }, "term_years" : 2 })

db.products.insert({ "_id" : { "oid" : "507d95d5719dbef170f15bff" }, "name" : "Phone Service Core Plan", "type" : "service", "monthly_price" : 60, "limits" : { "voice" : { "units" : "minutes", "n" : 1000, "over_rate" : 0.05 }, "data" : { "n" : "unlimited", "over_rate" : 0 }, "sms" : { "n" : "unlimited", "over_rate" : 0 } }, "term_years" : 1 })

db.products.insert({ "_id" : { "oid" : "507d95d5719dbef170f15c00" }, "name" : "Phone Service Family Plan", "type" : "service", "monthly_price" : 90, "limits" : { "voice" : { "units" : "minutes", "n" : 1200, "over_rate" : 0.05 }, "data" : { "n" : "unlimited", "over_rate" : 0 }, "sms" : { "n" : "unlimited", "over_rate" : 0 } }, "sales_tax" : true, "term_years" : 2 })

db.products.insert({ "_id" : { "oid" : "507d95d5719dbef170f15c01" }, "name" : "Cable TV Basic Service Package", "type" : "tv", "monthly_price" : 50, "term_years" : 2, "cancel_penalty" : 25, "sales_tax" : true, "additional_tarriffs" : [ { "kind" : "federal tarriff", "amount" : { "percent_of_service" : 0.06 } }, { "kind" : "misc tarriff", "amount" : 2.25 } ] })
```

Now, if I need to find , How many products types are TV I execute

```
db.products.find( { type : "tv" } ).count()
```

which returns 1 (correct).

Similarly, if I need to find **How many products have a voice limit**, what will be the query?

I tried with `db.products.find( { limits : "voice" } ).count()` but it returns 0 while it should be 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [exists](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) clause

```
db.products.find({ "limits.voice" : { $exists : true, $ne : null } })
```